# Rxjs observable to promise never resolved in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, rxjs

I've made a simplified example of the code I am working.

```
import * as rx from "rxjs";
import * as op from "rxjs/operators";

async function main(): Promise<void> {
    const blocker = new rx.ReplaySubject<0>();
    const subscription = rx.timer(0, 1000)
        .pipe(
            op.take(3),
            op.observeOn(rx.queueScheduler),
            op.subscribeOn(rx.queueScheduler)
        )
        .subscribe({
            next: x => console.log(`timer: next: [${x}]`),
            error: err => console.log(`timer: error: [${err}]`),
            complete: () => {
                console.log("timer: complete");
                blocker.next(0);
            }
        });
    const promise = rx.lastValueFrom(blocker.asObservable()
        .pipe(
            op.single(),
            op.observeOn(rx.queueScheduler),
            op.subscribeOn(rx.queueScheduler)
        ));
    console.log("prepared to await");
    await promise;
    console.log("awaited!");
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}

main()
    .then(
        () => console.log("all right"),
        reason => console.log(`rejected: [${reason}]`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`error! : ${err}`))
    .finally(() => console.log("done done done"));
```

It works (sorta) except the part when "awaited!" is never printed to console, as well as any of the lines after the promise returned by `main` function.

The actual console output is:

```
prepared to await
timer: next: [0]
timer: next: [1]
timer: next: [2]
timer: complete
```

And the one I expect is:

```
prepared to await
timer: next: [0]
timer: next: [1]
timer: next: [2]
timer: complete
awaited!
all right
```

Questions:

1. Why is that happening? What is the nodejs 'magic' (with scheduler, I assume) involved here? Could you recommend any books on nodejs internal involved here?
2. How to change the code to achieve expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is about schedulers or nodejs. `lastValueFrom` requires that the observable it is handed completes before it resolves the returned promise. In this case, it never completes.

#### One Solution

Try this:

```
blocker.next(0);
blocker.complete();
```

You should then get your expected output. Otherwise blocker never completes, which means it never emits a last value.

#### Another Solution

Replace

```ts
single()
```

with

```ts
take(1)
```

Then even though blocker itself doesn't complete, the observable you hand to `lastValueFrom` will complete. Which will resolve your promise.

#### Yet Another Solution

Try this:

```
blocker.next(0);
blocker.next(1);
```

You should then get your expected output. Though this time it will be `single` that resolves your promise with a `SequenceError` (instead of the previous examples in which the promise resolves with the value `0`).